# passing info from form in Page 1 to Page 2

Tags: javascript, html

I have HTML and I want to use js to pass some info from a form in page 1 to get a specific result in page 2 and I want to do a test on gender and user type to get on Page 2 the result and it will be like this:

```
function () client{
    var p = get.ElementById("name"); -
    var x = get.ElementById("choice").selectedIndex; *type of user*
    var h = get.ElementById('H'); *Gender*

    if (x[1] && h[0])
    {
        var pa = document.createElement("P");
        var t = document.createTextNode("hello", p ,"vous etes un" x[1]);
        pa.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(pa);
    }
    if (x[1] && h[1])
    {
        var pa = document.createElement("P");
        var t = document.createTextNode("hello", p ,"vous etes une ", x[1] ,"e");
        pa.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(pa);
    }
    if (X[2] && h[0]) 
    {
        var pa = document.createElement("P");
        var t = document.createTextNode("hello", p ,"vous etes un fournisseur");
        pa.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(pa);
    }
    if (X[2] && h[1]) 
    {
        var pa = document.createElement("P");
        var t = document.createTextNode("hello", p ,"vous etes une fournisseure");
        pa.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(pa);
    }
}
```

I expect pass the info and pass the to page 2

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the local storage api

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of localStorage and SessionStorage to store your data and retrieve, 
in Page1
localStorage.setItem(key,value)
and in Page2 
localStorage.getItem(key);

more info about these methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Simply create session variable

Answer (score 0):

Go for the local storage or maintain session varible